# built / had built

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple

> The steam engine is usually thought of as a relatively modern invention, but
>   the Greeks *had built / built* a kind of steam engine in ancient times.

In this sentence, between ***built*** and ***had built***, which one would you consider to be more appropriate? I think, while both being correct, *had built* makes a stronger contrast to the former statement.

This question is from the book *Advanced Language Practice* (BrE), which chooses *built* as the more appropriate. The reason I think *had built* is correct is that the first statement has an implied *built* in it (invention), and therefore makes it possible to use the past perfect.

Answer (score 1):

> The steam engine is usually thought of as a relatively modern
>   invention, but the Greeks **built** a kind of steam engine in
>   ancient times.

Yes, mixed tenses but this makes sense and is grammatically correct. On the other hand:

> The steam engine is usually thought of as a relatively modern
>   invention, but the Greeks **had** built a kind of steam engine in
>   ancient times.

No, unfortunately the first part of the sentence is in the *present* tense, meaning that the (pluperfect tense) **had built** cannot refer to it,, Ill show you how it might be made to relate, though. If we start out in the past tense..

> In 1606, Spaniard Jerónimo de Ayanz y Beaumont built what was thought
>   to be the first steam engine - but the Greeks **had** built a kind of
>   steam engine in ancient times.

~or you could say `

> The steam engine is usually thought of as a relatively modern
>   invention. In 1781 James watt unveiled his wonderful machine but  in
>   ancient times the Greeks **had** built a kind of steam engine.

See what I mean? You have to be speaking in the past to be able to use the word "had" before the verb about something as having already happened even earlier.

The words "in ancient times" also get in the way and make it awkward. To make it really simple:

> James Watt claimed he invented the steam engine but the ancient Greeks
>   had built them long beforehand.